# Merge multilinestrings that are out of order

Tags: r, sf

I am trying to merge a `multilinestring` object to create a single `linestring` object and it looks like the `st_line_merge` function is appropriate for this purpose. However, it only seems to work when the line segments are "in order".

Consider this first code block that makes a `LINESTRING`:

```
mls1 = st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(0,0), c(0.5, 0.7), c(1,1)), 
                              rbind(c(2,0), c(1,1)), 
                              rbind(c(2,0),c(5,0))))
st_line_merge(mls1)
```

Compare with this block that **does not** create a `LINESTRING`:

```
mls2 = st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(0,0), c(0.5, 0.7), c(1,1)), 
                              rbind(c(2,0), c(1,1)), 
                              rbind(c(0.5,0.7),c(-1,2))))
st_line_merge(mls2)
```

How can I make `mls2` into a `LINESTRING` not a `MULTILINESTRING`?

Comment: a LINESTRING is an ordered set of coordinate pairs describing a single linear chain. Your second example `mls2` is three linear chains, which you can't make into a single LINESTRING - did you try plotting it? R actually merges two of your linear chains to make a MULTILINESTRING with 2 elements, which is the best it can do. What did you expect?

Comment: Ah, I thought the second example was doing nothing because the postgis docs say _If can't be merged - original MULTILINESTRING is returned_ (http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_LineMerge.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was ultimately after something like this where the original geometry is cut down from 4 lines to 3:

```
library(sf)
lines <- st_sfc(list(st_linestring(rbind(c(0,0), c(0.5, 0.7))), 
                    st_linestring(rbind(c(0.5, 0.7), c(1, 1))), 
                    st_linestring(rbind(c(2,0), c(1,1))), 
                    st_linestring(rbind(c(1,1), c(1, 3)))))

lines_merged <- st_cast(st_line_merge(
    st_union(st_cast(lines, "MULTILINESTRING"))), "LINESTRING")

lines
lines_merged
```